# How can i get sub array value to main array key? [Php]

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. This array have a sub arrays. I want to take sub array value to main array keys. Here is my example array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index-id] => 12
            [title] => Example Title
            [description] => Example Description
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [index-id] => 32
            [title] => Example Title
            [description] => Example Description
        )
)
```

i want to take *index-id* to **main array key** my array must be like this

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [index-id] => 12
            [title] => Example Title
            [description] => Example Description
        )
    [32] => Array
        (
            [index-id] => 32
            [title] => Example Title
            [description] => Example Description
        )
)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at `array_column()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short solution using `array_column` and `array_combine` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$result = array_combine(array_column($arr, 'index-id'), $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $temp[$v['index-id']] = $v;
}
print_r($temp);
```

Where `$temp` is result array, `$arr` is your array.